# WooCommerce: How to calculate and list total weight of each order with status 'on hold' and calculate total amount and total weight for all orders

Tags: php, woocommerce, sum, orders, product-quantity

I was reflecting and researching for some time on how to achieve this without direct SQL queries and in accordance with good woocommerce practice.

I have some WooCommerce, PHP, SQL, HTML, CSS knowledge since last year.

I hope my code may be useful for someone searching in vain to do this on the net.

Please let me know your suggestions in ameliorating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function kg_total(){
    
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Total weight (kg):</h2>
    </div>
    <?php   
    
    $order_weight = 0;
    $orders_weight = 0;
    
    $on_hold_orders = wc_get_orders( array(
    'limit' => -1,
    // 'customer_id' => $user->ID,
    'post_type' => 'shop_order',
    'status'    => 'on-hold',
    ) );
    
    ?>
    <table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-sort="int">order_ID</th>
            <th data-sort="string">order_weight</th>
            <th data-sort="string">last name</th>
            <th data-sort="string">first name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody> 
    <?php
    
    foreach( $on_hold_orders as $order) {
        // Gesamt €
        $total_amount += $order->get_total();
        
        foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        // Gesamt kg per order
        if ( $item['product_id'] > 0 ) {
            $_product = $item->get_product();
                if ( ! $_product->is_virtual() ) {
                    $order_weight += $_product->get_weight() * $item['qty'];

                }
            }
        }
        $orders_weight = $orders_weight + $order_weight;
        
        echo '<td style="color: #0000aa;"><b>' . $order->get_id() . '</b></td>';
        echo '<td style="text-align:right;"><b>' . $order_weight . ' kg - </b></td>';
        echo '<td>' . '<b>' . strtoupper( $order->get_billing_last_name() ) . '</b>' . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $order->get_billing_first_name() . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
                
        $order_weight = 0;
        
    }
    echo '</tbody>';
    
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<p style="color: #0000aa; font-size: 20px;"><b>Total amount (on hold): ' . $total_amount . ' €</b></p>';
    echo '<p style="color: #aa0000; font-size: 20px;"><b>Total weight (on hold): ' . $orders_weight . ' kg</b></p>';
        
}
```